# WordPress get_terms() called by wp_axax_ inside a class method, returns "Invalid taxonomy"

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

WordPress get_terms() called by wp_axax_ inside a class method, returns "Invalid taxonomy"
Code example:

```
class MyClass{
public function __construct(){
 add_action('wp_ajax_get-terms-action',array($this,'get_terms_method'));
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get-terms-action',array($this,'get_terms_method'));
}

 public function get_terms_method(){
  $result = get_terms('taxonomy_name');
 }
}
```

Comment: well, did you check your 'taxonomy_name' is actually the name that you registered

Comment: Yes, 'taxonomy_name' is a valid registered tax name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "invalid taxonomy" message occurs because when the ajax call is made, not all the taxonomies have been registered because all the plugins have not been initialized.

the solution is to launch the ajax after the initialization and so it works ok

ex.

```
class MyClass {

    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'init', function() {

            //add the ajax hook only when all the taxonomies have been registered
            add_action('wp_ajax_get-terms-action',  function() {

                $result = get_terms( 'taxonomy_name' );
            }

        }, 99);

    }
}
```